# Can a Polymorphed creature still command a Dancing Sword?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, polymorph

If a creature has been Polymorphed into a beast, can it still use an already summoned Dancing Sword to attack?

[Polymorph](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/polymorph) says:

> The target's game statistics, including mental ability scores, are replaced by the
> statistics of the chosen beast. It retains its alignment and personality.
>
> ...
>
> The creature is limited in the actions it can perform by the nature of
> its new form, and it can't speak, cast spells, or take any other
> action that requires hands or speech.
>
> The target's gear melds into the new form. The creature can't
> activate, use, wield, or otherwise benefit from any of its equipment.

[Dancing Sword](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/dancing-sword) says:

> While the sword hovers, you can use a bonus action to cause it to fly
> up to 30 feet to another spot within 30 feet of you. As part of the
> same bonus action, you can cause the sword to attack one creature
> within 5 feet of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### RAW, probably, but it is up to the DM.

The description of how you use the dancing sword after you speak the command word is quite vague:

> you can cause the sword to attack

There is no description of how you cause it to move and attack. So RAW, a *polymorphed* dancing sword owner should have no trouble commanding the dancing sword *as long as they spoke the command word before they were Polymorphed*.

The trouble with *polymorph* is that you often relinquish your ability to speak - no speaking command words while in a beast form.

But sense the description of dancing sword says “you can cause”, not “you can verbally command”, there should be no issue commanding the dancing sword, unless the DM rules otherwise - which would still be a reasonable ruling.

Comment: Regarding how this could work logically, one way to explain it is that the sword senses its user's hostile intent toward a creature and acts upon it. A polymorphed creature is certainly still capable of thinking hostile thoughts toward an enemy, especially considering the creature retains its alignment and personality.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, it should still work**

The bonus action in question does not state that any "somatic" or "verbal" components are needed, just that it happens when you "cause it to".

> You can use a bonus action to toss this magic sword into the air and speak the command word. When you do so, the sword **begins to hover**, flies up to 30 feet, and attacks one creature of your choice within 5 feet of it. The sword uses your attack roll and ability score modifier to damage rolls.

> **While the sword hovers**, you can use a bonus action to **cause** it to fly up to 30 feet to another spot within 30 feet of you. As part of the same bonus action, you can cause the sword to attack one creature within 5 feet of it.

(Emphasis mine)

As it says, whilst the sword hovers, the bonus action to cause it to fly and attack is able to be used. This is not to say that you can use the command word to cause it to hover in the first place, but you already acknowledge this anyway.